# PLSQL: Subjob as new session?

Tags: oracle, session, plsql

I know there is pragma autonomous_transaction. But can I get more than that?

I want to start a subroutine (procedure in a package) completely isolated from the calling routine.

I.e.:

- The subroutine shall not end when the calling routine ends.
- The calling routine continues to work without having to wait for the subroutine to finish.

So basically, I want to start a new session and run the subroutine within this session. But how do I archive this?

Best, Peter

Comment: What is wrong with an `autonomous_transaction`?

Comment: @MTO, it seems like atonomous_transaction does stop once the main session dies. furthermore, the main session has to wait for it. In my current context (web user triggers database job) this is both: dangerous for the DB Job and annoying for the user.

Comment: I would be surprised if the calling procedure has wait for it (if that is what you mean by the "main session"). It more seems like you have not actually made the procedure autonomous and it is running as a normal procedure (which would cause the calling procedure to wait).

Comment: hm, maybe it is because the "procedure" actually is a function. :-) Maybe this is the issue. So you say that AT should not terminate once main is killed - say due to disconnect. Right? Then I might test this with a procedure first. ... earlier I added 
        pragma autonomous_transaction; to the function especially because I wanted to commit things despite working with database links.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "subroutine" is - actually - a stored procedure (if not, make it so), then one option to do that is to **schedule** it from the main (calling) procedure; it would run *right now* and only once. Doing so, main procedure would continue doing what it does, and *subroutine* would separately do whatever it does.

Use `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Basically, you'd

```
create procedure p_main is
begin
   ... do something here

   -- call subroutine
   dbms_scheduler.create_job(..., p_subroutine, ...)

   ... continue main procedure
end
```